# MongoDB sort by relevance (mix $and and $or)

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

with 2 documents like :

```
{
    "name": "hello",
    "family": 1
},
{
    "name": "world",
    "family": 1,
    "category": 2
}
```

and a query like :

```
doc.find({$or: [{family: 1}, {category: 2}]})
```

how can i have results sorted with the one matching the 2 conditions ("world") as a first result but still have the doc matching only 1 condition as a last result ("hello") ?

i can't use the default $and operator as i would not see the "hello" document that do not match both conditions.

i saw how aggregation could help but for a more complex example than that it would be a lot of computation, i'm guessing this is common use case and there must be something obvious i'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that sort of query (pun not intended) with a simple `.find()` statement. What you are asking for involves "weighting", which is applying a "calculated precedence to values.

Anything with "calculation" basically conditions to be programmatically applied, and the particular assertion here to "sort" rules out the "JavaScript runner" options like `mapReduce` and simply leaves the Aggregation Framework *or* other handling of the results.

For the aggregation framework approach you would need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) a calculated "weight" to each matched document based on the conditions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Same match conditions to filter
  { "$match": { "$or": [{ "family": 1, }, { "category": 2 }] } },

  // Assign the "weight" based on conditions
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "family": 1,
    "weight": {
      "$add": [
        { "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$family", 1 ] }, 
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }},
        { "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$category", 2 ] },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }}
      ] 
    }
  }},

  // Then sort "descending" with highest "weight" on top
  { "$sort": { "weight": -1 } }
])
```

Basically you are using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to evaluate the condition that the returned document actually has data meeting your condition, since in the selection either field being present is a valid response. Where the condition is present we assign a value, and where not the value is `0`.

When "both" conditions are present the [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operation combines the total in the weight. So here documents that met only one condition have a `1` and for both they have `2`. If you waned for example "family" to have the greater preference, then you would assign `2` in the condition, leaving you with possible document scores of:

- **3** : For both category **and** family
- **2** : For family only
- **1** : For category only

You could shorten the syntax of the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in MongoDB 3.4 or later with the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) pipeline operator instead, which is most useful when you have a "lot" of other document properties you want to return without needing to list them all in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

---

Aside from this, the database services don't allow for *"calculations"* on the "sort". This is considered "manipulation", which is the purpose of the Aggregation Framework.

Whilst you can do the same sort of "weighting" by post processing the result set in client code, the issue here is of course where you want to "limit" the results to return in actions like "paging". This is where running the operations on the server comes into play, and the reason why you use the Aggregation Framework for this.